# WordPress - Pass template location into pagination array

Tags: php, wordpress, svg, pagination

I'm wanting to pass in an svg arrow image as the prev_text and next_text of a WordPress post pagination loop. Currently, I have the localhost urls hard coded in. I want to set it up so these use get_template_directory_uri() or similar.

Current code:

```
<?php
  $big = 999999999;

  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
     'format' => '?paged=%#%',
     'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
     'next_text' => ('<img class="next-arrow" src="http://localhost:8888/mockingbird/wp-content/themes/mockingbird/images/arrow.svg" alt="next posts"/>'),
     'prev_text' => ('<img class="prev-arrow" src="http://localhost:8888/mockingbird/wp-content/themes/mockingbird/images/arrow.svg" alt="previous posts"/>'),
     'total' => $query->max_num_pages
   ) );
?>
```

Psuedo code of what I want is as follows:

```
'next_text' => ('<img class="next-arrow" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/arrow.svg" alt="next posts"/>'),
'prev_text' => ('<img class="prev-arrow" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/arrow.svg" alt="previous posts"/>'),
```

So my question is, is it possible to pass in php inside of an array's string?

If not, how can I achieve this without hard coding in my urls?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution by setting the next_text and prev_text to empty strings, then setting the arrow.svg as the background image of the next and previous links in my css.

This way, my image url is a relative path set in my css.

```
<?php
  $big = 999999999;

  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'next_text' => (''),
    'prev_text' => (''),
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

CSS:

```
&.next {
  background-color: $transparent;
  background-image: url('images/arrow.svg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

&.prev {
  background-color: $transparent;
  background-image: url('images/arrow.svg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```